# Select document based on matching Id in document property's collection

Tags: ravendb

I would like to retrieve a document if one of its collections has an item with a certain Id in it. This is the query I have:

```
var query = from x in session.Query<MailPackageLog>()
            where x.Package != null
            where ((x.Package.To != null && x.Package.To.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(recipientId))
            || (x.Package.Cc != null && x.Package.Cc.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(recipientId))
            || (x.Package.Bcc != null && x.Package.Bcc.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(recipientId)))
            select x;

query = query.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow(Settings.Default.DocumentStoreQueryTimeout));

return query.FirstOrDefault();
```

But I am getting this exception when it runs:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot understand how to translate
>   x.Package.To.Select(y => y.Id)

Is this a bug or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
x.Package.To.Select(y => y.Id).Contains(recipientId)
```

Try this:

```
x.Package.To.Any(y => y.Id == recipientId)
```

Semantically they are the same, but Raven may have an easier time translating the second one.

You may also wish to review the ["Filtering" section of the RavenDB documentation.](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/indexes/querying/filtering)  This is similar to the "Where + Any" example show there.

Comment: The bad thing with LINQ is that the same query can work on one system but not another (for example I know my original query would have worked using EF/SQL) but the good thing is that there is always another LINQy way to accomplish the same thing. Thanks!